# Can we access the new "Memories" feature via PhotoKit on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, ios11, photokit

With iOS 11 Apple have introduces the amazing new memories feature to their photo app that intelligently pulls together photos into collections and assigns some super nifty metadata to them and their estimated importance to the user!

I know that on MacOS we can access this info via PHProjectInfo if we are create a project extension for the photos app (as detailed here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/505/?time=1728 ish)

Has anyone found anyway to access memories from the iOS photo library in an iOS 11 app?